# Make weighted edge list like pairs to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with three columns.

```
X = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "w")
Y = c("a", "b", "c" , "b", "a", "c")
set.seed(3)
Z = sample(10,6)
dat = data.frame(X, Y, Z)
```

The dat looks like

```
 X Y Z
1 x a 2
2 y b 8
3 z c 4
4 x b 3
5 y a 9
6 w c 6
```

I want to transform the above data into the format that the rows are X and the columns are Y and the values in the matrix are Z. Essentially I want the following:

```
    a   b    c
x   2   3    0
y   9   8    0
z   0   0    4
w   0   0    6
```

This is somewhat similar to edge list to adjacency matrix, except the data matrix is not square. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
library(reshape2)
acast(dat, X~Y, value.var='Z', fill=0)
```

To get the rows in order as the expected result

```
acast(dat, factor(X, levels=unique(X))~Y, value.var='Z', fill=0)
```

Or as @thelatemail commented

```
xtabs(Z~X+Y, data= dat)[unique(dat$X),]
```

Or a modified version if both columns are not in order

```
with(dat, xtabs(Z ~ X + Y)[unique(X), unique(Y)])
```

Comment: `xtabs(Z ~ X + Y, data=dat)[unique(dat$X),unique(dat$Y)]` if you're fussy about the rows and columns being in that order

Comment: `xtabs(Z ~ X + Y, data=dat)[unique(X),]` should do it too. edit: you edited it right after I posted : )

Comment: And since I'm being annoying - `with(dat, xtabs(Z ~ X + Y)[unique(X), unique(Y)])` might wrap it all up.

Comment: so clean @thelatemail! :)